# how to use InstaPy to send direct messages to users?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instapy

I've used python [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) in order to create web scraping bots for a while.

Recently I found [InstaPy](https://github.com/InstaPy) and I've leveraged it to increase followers of some Instagram pages.

Now some of the page owners need to interact with users privately through direct messages.
I want to know is there any features to send direct messages to users and interact with them in InstaPy?

Answer (score 0):

Instapy doesn't offer you the possibility to send DMs.

This is another approach using selenium that could fix your problem ( see sendMessage function): https://github.com/CamTosh/instagram-bot-dm/blob/master/instadm.py

Comment: Thank you @Ali for your response, I checked the library you mentioned but I need a solution based on InstaPy or somehow extend it, on the grounds that I have already built a bot utilizing InstaPy and need to extend it to meet the user's requirements.